# How to run react native with different App.js file

Tags: react-native, package.json, metro-bundler

Sometimes I need to run my react native app with different `App.js` file, lets call it `App2.js`.
I'm modifying `index.js` manually.

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'

//const myApp = require('./src/App2').default
const myApp = require('./src/App').default

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Dummy app, () => myApp)
```

Is it possible to add script to package.json for this?
Something like `react-native start:app2` or in different way.

I looked to react native cli [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-plugin-metro/README.md#start) and `start` command doesn't have anything similar. Only `--projectRoot` which is not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Open your package.json file.
Add a new script entry with a custom name, such as "start:app2", and set its value to the command you want to execute. In this case, it will be the modified index.js file that imports App2.js. Your updated package.json script section should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  "start:app2": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --entry-file ./src/App2.js"
}
```

Comment: Hi Juan. Thanks for your answer.
I have next error:
`error: unknown option --entry-file'`

It seems like `--entry-file` is not a param for `start` but for `bundle`

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-dotenv.
`npm install --save react-native-dotenv`

Config should be:

index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App1 from './App1.js';
import App2 from './App2.js';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import {APP_NAME} from '@env';

const apps = {
  app1: App1,
  app2: App2,
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => apps[APP_NAME]);
```

finally on package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "app1": "APP_NAME=app1 npx react-native start --reset-cache", <== this
    "app2": "APP_NAME=app2 npx react-native start --reset-cache" <== this
  },
```

Please note that reset cache option is required.